# How to consume provider inside another provider

Tags: flutter

I need to consume a Provider inside another Provider, but I'm not able to do it, I was trying to use `ChangeNotifierProxyProvider` but the update function is not called.

I have 2 providers, UserProvider and RoleProvider, and I need to call RoleProvider inside UserProvider or to call RoleProvider once UserProvider is updated with a logged user.

```
providers: [
  ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (ctx) => UserProvider(),),
  ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<UserProvider, RoleProvider>(
    create: (_) => RoleProvider(null),
    update: (_, userProvider, roleProvider) => RoleProvider(userProvider),
  ),
],

class UserProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  User user;

  Future<void> login(String username, String password) async {  
    this.loginMessage = '';
    try {
      // Login Process
      this.user = new User();
      // When there is a new logged user, I need to doSomething in RoleProvider
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      this.loginMessage = 'ERROR';
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class RoleProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  final UserProvider userProvider;
  List<Student> students;

  RoleProvider(this.userProvider) {
    print('PARENT PROVIDER CONSTRUCTOR');
  }

  fetchData() {
    print('TEEEEEEEEST');
  }

}
```

Comment: try removing the `create: (_) => RoleProvider(null),` and just use `update: (_, userProvider, roleProvider) => roleProvider ?? RoleProvider(userProvider),` instead

Answer (score 2):

```
providers: [
  ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (ctx) => UserProvider(),),
  ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<UserProvider, RoleProvider>(
    create: (_) => RoleProvider(),
    update: (_, userProvider, roleProvider) => roleprovider.userProvider = userProvider,
    // use the roleProvider reference instead of creating a new RoleProvider in the update
  ),
],

class RoleProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  UserProvider userProvider; // No final, if you want to consume one provider inside another
                             // then just leave it so you can then update its value
  List<Student> students;

  // No need to use the constructor if you're not going to do anything else besides declare userProvider

  fetchData() {
    print('TEEEEEEEEST');
  }

}
```

Comment: does this work...?
i am not able to make it work. I have provider that show list of items
and i wanted to pass list of items provider into provider that set SortAndFilter parameters and based on that i wanted to call loadListWithParams() which is a function in list based provider

Comment: you would need to submit a new question for people to check what you're trying to do